# How to use "overflow:hidden" for images within "position:fixed"?

Tags: html, css, overflow

I have a `DIV` with `CSS`

```
#parent{
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    left:10px;
    overflow:hidden;
    width:100%;
}
```

I want to have only one line of images, instead of flowing to the second line.

See the [EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/27pDc/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#parent{
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    left:10px;
    overflow:hidden;
    width:100%;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/27pDc/2/

Comment: @All happens to everyone.  Glad I could help.

Answer (score 1):

You can specify a height. [Updated demo](http://jsfiddle.net/27pDc/1/)

```
#parent{
    ...
    height: 100px;
}
```

Comment: sorry, yes that better fits my need, but thanks for your care.